# query is not working after upgrade Hibernate/Quarkus upgrade

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

```
 
        sortOrder="Descending"
        sortColumn = "SIZE(i.builds)"
        final Sort sortSpecification = Sort.by(sortColumn, sortOrder, NULLS_LAST);     

        result = find(
                """
                SELECT DISTINCT i
                FROM db1 i LEFT JOIN FETCH i.books
                WHERE i in :reporters
                """,
                sortSpecification,
                Parameters.with("reporters", reporters))
                .list();
```

**after I upgrade Hibernate from 5.6 to 6.2 and  Quarkus framework from 2.16.6 to 3.0.1 the query is not working.
The error is
ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list**

I don't want to add to the SIZE(i.builds) because then the result will be another column

Any idea what was the change from Hibernate from 5.6 to 6.2 ? or quarkus framework from 2.16.6 to 3.0.1 ?

How I can solve it ?

Comment: Can you share what SQL Hibernate 5.6 with Quarkus 2 vs 6.2 with 3 generated? I'd like to understand if the problem is SQL related or rather H2 version related.